# Declare two objects into one list?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

What I have in place is working fine. I'm curious if there is a better way to accomplish this via Linq. Currently I'm declaring an ArrayList, filling that then running through that later. Can I run a single linq statement to pull the Windows programs then append the Linux programs to the list?

```
foreach (var winProgram in allWinPrograms.Descendants("Programs").Select(p => new
{
    progName = p.Element("ProgramName").Value
}))
{
    alTemp.Add(winProgram.progName.ToString());
}

foreach (var linProgram in allLinPrograms.Descendants("Programs").Select(p => new
{
    progName = p.Element("ProgramName").Value
}))
{
    alTemp.Add(linProgram.progName.ToString());
}

foreach (string newProgram in alTemp)
{
    if (!alPrograms.Contains(newProgram))
    {
        alPrograms.Add(newProgram);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that descendants of `allWinPrograms` and `allLinPrograms` are of the same type, you should be able to use LINQ's `Concat` like this:

```
var sorted = allWinPrograms.Descendants("Programs")
    .Concat(allLinPrograms.Descendants("Programs"))
    .Select(p => p.Element("ProgramName").Value.ToString())
    .Distinct();
```

Comment: Note that if the list he's adding these items to had items in it before the start he can use `AddRange` to add the items (based on the query in this answer) to the list.  If not, then it's likely possible to just use `ToList` and replace the list entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Short solution

```cs
foreach (var prg in allWinPrograms.Union(allLinPrograms).Select(x => x).Where(prg =>!allPrograms.Contains(prg)))
{
    allPrograms.Add(prg);
}
```

Long solution

```cs
foreach (var prg in allWinPrograms.Union(allLinPrograms).Select(x => x))
{
     if (!allPrograms.Contains(prg))
     {
         allPrograms.Add(prg);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

How readable is it going to be if you get everything in the same line? You might get some performance benefits out of the linq execution, but remember about clean code as well.

```
        foreach (var winProgram in allWinPrograms.Descendants("Programs").Select(p => new
        {
            progName = p.Element("ProgramName").Value
        }))
        {
            alTemp.Add(winProgram.progName);
        }

        foreach (var linProgram in allLinPrograms.Descendants("Programs").Select(p => new
        {
            progName = p.Element("ProgramName").Value
        }))
        {
            alTemp.Add(linProgram.progName);
        }

        foreach (string newProgram in alTemp.Cast<string>().Where(newProgram => !alPrograms.Contains(newProgram)))
        {
            alPrograms.Add(newProgram);
        }
```

Comment: For whoever downvote my answer please read:http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882, and maybe choose another profession ;)

Comment: It seems all answers in this question inexplicably got a down vote in the pass few minutes.

Comment: Correction: It seems someone downvoted your answer, and in response you decided to downvote everyone else who took the time to answer.